# Add optional parameter to get only paging information?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

On methods that support total/page/pagesize add an optional parameter to get just those fields when making a request. (pageInfo=true).

I am thinking specifically in apps that have real-time like features, a light-weight call would be handy. If this feature were implemented perhaps lastActivity would be useful to be returned as well.

Comment: + very sound suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pagesize=0` is now permitted.

You can use this to get `total` on all the methods that support paging, *generally* very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be sufficient if adding the parameter `pagesize=0` returned the expected result.

Comment: No...the default page size is handy for paging calculations. I would hate to rely on 30 as the default then have that change. Magic numbers are bad.

Comment: @TheHurt: I'm not talking about a magic number.  I'm saying if you explicitly specify that the page size should be 0, then it should return nothing but the page info and an empty list.  Adding `pagesize=0` as a URL parameter currently doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: I think that would be fine in addition to what I am asking for. This is about my needs Bill, and I need you to be sensitive to that.